# Hi, how i can have multiple graphics within a Activity? (MPAndroidChart)

Tags: android, graphics, mpandroidchart

how i can have multiple graphics within a Activity? (MPAndroidChart)

I try put multiple graphics but the second replaced the first :c

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/estado_total_grafica_Temperatura"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/estado_total_grafica_Humedad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: ok, you can't get any answer here if you don't post all infos. What is the surrounding layout in you xml?

Comment: In aChartEngine you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue concerning the chart library.
It seems like you have not properly understood how android-layout in xml works.

I strongly suggest that you read the [android developer layout guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

As for the simple example above, try the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/estado_total_grafica_Temperatura"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

   <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/estado_total_grafica_Humedad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will place the charts in a linear layout vertically, using the `weight` property.